# Changing collation on Laravel migration generates problem

Tags: mysql, laravel, caching, migration, collation

I'm trying to change column collation from Latin1 to UTF8 with Laravel migration, with no success.
Then, I've tried to do something like this:

> 

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('database')->table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name_new')->collation('utf8_bin')->nullable();
        });

        DB::connection('database')
            ->statement("UPDATE table SET name_new = name");

        Schema::connection('database')->table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('name');
            $table->renameColumn('name_new', 'name');
        });
    }
```

The problem is, the column 'name' remains Latin1. I've tried to comment the line

> $table->renameColumn('name_new', 'name');

and the column was still UTF-8 nonetheless. I then tried to change the column name from 'name_new' to 'name' directly on PhpMyAdmin and the collation remains UTF-8. What left me confuse: is laravel migration caching collation based on column names somehow?

Comment: Schema::connection('database')->table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name_new')->collation('utf8_bin')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->change();
        });

Comment: Could you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

For each table:

```
ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

If you need the reverse procedure, that gets messier.

Before the `CONVERTs`...  Do you already have some non-ascii text in the tables?  If so, I suggest you do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to see whether it was stored correctly.